# macOS Mojave stuck on 100% loading screen

Tags: macos, boot, macos-mojave

Just restart macOS 10.14.1 Mojave and it’s stuck on 100% loading bar screen. I’ve tried save restart, verbose, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and others. Nothing helped. Check my disk driver with Disk Utility – everything ok, no errors. Check 15+ forums on apple forums – nothing helped.

So I’ve made a screenshot of <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (verbose) restart, is there something special that can help find the problem?

Verbose screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive might have issues even if it passes disk utility.  I would plug into another mac via thunderbolt or firewire and put it into target disk mode (option+t) during startup.

It should show up in the finder of the other machine.  that should give you an opportunity to salvage the data....